# What's the difference between `dest` and `dist`?

Tags: javascript, gulp

In gulp or grunt we often write the following code

```
gulp.src('*')
  .pipe(rev())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
```

Here, what's the difference between `dest` and `dist`? I have saw some project both use `dest`.
Is it that `dest` means `destination` and `dist` means `distribution`?

Comment: It's just a folder name.

Comment: `dest` is a gulp method showing gulp where to put the completed files. In this instance `dist` the name of a folder, but it could be anything.

Answer (score 3):

As `gulp.src()` defines the source of the files that you wish to pipe with gulp, `gulp.dest()` defines the destination of the files after they have passed through the pipe.

In this case, `"dist/"` is the name of the destination folder, it is a commonly used short form of the distribution folder which is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

You are right `dest` means destination,there are several ways to define src-dest (source-destination) file mappings, offering varying degrees of verbosity and control. ([refer](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks)).

And the `dist` optionally define a path to be append to the path (file.base) specified in `gulp.dest()`.

Hope I was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use 'blablah' in the end if you want. It just defines destination folder